# How do i select text with regex based on tag and class content in html?

Tags: html, regex, html-parsing

I have an html tag as a string. If 'md' is included in the class attribute in this tag, I want to select it and get the expression in the tag.

Example:

`'<tag class="...blah md blah...">(expression)</tag>`

- `<tag></tag>` is first selector
- Class attribute included `md` is second selector
- At the same time, the tag should not be empty.

I mean, I need a regex that starts with `<tag>` and ends with `</tag>` and gives tag with `md` in **class attribute**, but I couldn't get out of it.

What I did is trying to select those with direct md attribute, but this is wrong. Also problem with nested tag ones as well.

```
(<b md(?!<|>).+>|<b \S+ md>|<b md>|<b .+ md .+>)(.+)(<\/b>)
```

https://regex101.com/r/3Vv0WG/1

I decided that the correct form is in the class attribute, but I could not write this regex. Thanks for your help.

Example:

- `'<b class="... md ..."></b>'` not match because tag is empty
- `'<i class="..."></i>'` not match because class attribute not include md
- `<span class="...md...">ANYTHING</span>` match

It would be more appropriate not to be nested because it causes chaos in the code.

Comment: Why not use the dom and javascript with `classList.contains()` or a domparser?

Comment: This is in a replacement loop and I have a string, not an html element, I need to replace the text that conforms to this condition so I have to check the class with regex as it is not a dom element, and I also need to check its tag.

Comment: Can there be nested elements?

Comment: May depend on the condition :)

Comment: @RıdvanOnal 4th bird asks probably, because it's a whole lot different, if there can occur nested tags e.g. `<b>abc<b>de</b></b>`. Maybe you could clarify your question a bit, with scenarios, input, expected outcome, what tool you're using...

Comment: Exactly :-) You might get away with https://regex101.com/r/Girb1Y/1 but this can easily break, and reading the string with a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) might still be a better option.

Comment: It would be more appropriate not to be nested because it causes chaos in the code.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/Girb1Y/1 This was exactly the regex I was looking for. I will add this as an answer to the question. If you post it as an answer I can confirm it. @Thefourthbird

Comment: The question has been updated and I think is pretty clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no parser or dom available and can only get the parts from the string  with a pattern, you might get away with:

```
<(\w+) [^<>]*\bclass\s*=\s*"[^"]*\bmd\b[^"]*"[^<>]*>[^<>]+<\/\1>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZDJXaG/1)

Notes

- `[^` Means a negated character class matching any char except what is listed
- `(\w+)` captures 1+ word chars in group 1, and `\1` is a backreference to match the same as group 1
- The pattern assumes that for the `ANYTHING` parts there are no chars `<` or `>`
- The `md` is matched between word boundaries, preventing a partial match with another "word"

**»** Food for thought, read about [tony the pony](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).